# How can I apply multiple buttons as if they were a continuous text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to figure how to build a link structure on a website that follows this image:

[image]

Would be like if the `<button>` tag worked like a `<span>` tag, this:

```
<button>Cracked Compass Media</button>
<button>Rubato Chocolate</button>
<button>Teacher Paula G</button>
```

looking like this:

```
<span>Cracked Compass Media</span>
<span>Rubato Chocolate<span>
<span>Teacher Paula G<span>
```

It needs to be a `<button>` tag in order to the JS associated function properly, the `<a>` tag doesn't work

So far I tried to solve by using the `display` style in CSS, but either the line breaks on each button, being like:

```
Cracked Compass Media <br>
Rubato Chocolate <br>
Teacher Paula Gabriela
```

or it forces line breaks where it shoudn't, like a table:

```
|    Cracked     |    Rubato        |   Teacher   |   (...)  
|    Compass   |    Chocolate   |   Paula       |
|    Media        |                       |   G             |
```

It seemed to be such a simple concept at the start, but I really got stuck on this one hahah

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: _"It needs to be a <button> tag in order to the JS associated function properly"_: this part isn't clear - can you add some more details along with the code David suggested? You should be able to do this with spans though.

Comment: You can use CSS to make the buttons display how you like.

Comment: You don't necessarily need a `button` tag, you can get the click event on a `span`, and take action on the click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear why you're having problems with anchors (`<a>`). You can style anchors just like any other element, and maintain the links as you need.

```css
nav { font-size: 3em; background-color: black; padding: 0.25em; width: 450px; }
a, a.link, a.visited { color: darkgray; text-decoration: none; font-weight: 600; }
a:hover { color: gold; cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="http://example.com/cracked">Cracked Compass Media</a>
  <a href="http://example.com/rubato">Rubato Chocolate</a>
  <a href="http://example.com/teacher">Teacher Paula G</a>
</nav>
```